# NestJS: New instance of HttpModule per module import

Tags: typescript, axios, nestjs

My nestjs system is a system that connects to multiple systems via API calls.

For each system, I created a Module to handle their processes. Each of these modules imports `HttpModule`.

I want to have separate Axios interceptors for each of these modules' HttpModule.

This is my attempt to test the functionality:

on `a.module.ts`:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    HttpModule,
    // Other imports
  ],
  // controllers, providers and exports here
})
export class ModuleA implements OnModuleInit {
  constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpService) { }
  public onModuleInit() {
    this.httpService.axiosRef.interceptors.request.use(async (config: Axios.AxiosRequestConfig) => {
      console.log('Module A Interceptor');    
      return config;
    });
  }
}
```

The module class for Module B is similar, with a different message in the `console.log` call.

I tried making a http call to System B using a service in Module B, but both messages are displayed in the console.

I figured that the http module is a singleton across the system, so how do I instantiate a separate `HttpModule` for Module A and Module B?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading the documentation on [Dynamic Modules](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/dynamic-modules) and [this bug report](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1098), it turns out that calling the `register()` method in the import creates a separate instance of the `HttpModule`.

So my solution is to call the `register()` and pass in an empty object on both Module's `@Module` declaration.

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    HttpModule.register({}),
  ],
  // providers and exports
})
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct way of doing it, but it seems to work.

Comment: Don't you know how to access this particular instance of HttpService while testing?